# Difficulty understanding continuously updating data in GUI

Tags: java, swing, loops, user-interface, updating

I am developing a program that is able to read through records from a database, pull information upon a certain trigger, and then displays that information the GUI.

My current strategy is for the main method in MainDisplay.java to:

1. create connection with DB using method from Dataase.java
2. run query with method from Database.java
3. store result set elements into the program using method from Database.java
4. use setters and getters to give data to main
5. then use mroe setters and getters to give data to ThreatPanel.java to display data in GUI
6. sleep for 10 seconds
7. while there is another result, repeat.

What I am getting is the data being written over eachoher in the GUI, no pauses. I have a feeling I am either faulty in my logic or lacking in my understanding with GUI elements. Could anyone shed some light on the matter? I am a fairly new programmer.

Comment: _Don't_ sleep on the EDT; _do_ see [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).